# Python: Running imported functions locally

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am designing a module (its function is irrelevant) and I want to call a function from within the module (in this example `foo.setup()`, `foo` being the module) and the function is something along these lines:

```
def setup():
    global a, b, c
    a = foo.a
    b = foo.b
    c = foo.c
```

with `a`, `b`, and `c` being variables (well actually classes but they're treated the same, no need to overcomplicate) from withinside `foo.py` (the module), and the function is to make `a`, `b`, and `c` easier to refer to than `foo.a`, etc.

Now in a file (`project.py`) importing the `foo` module this is the code:

```
import foo
foo.setup()
```

But instead of defining `a`, `b`, and `c` in `project.py` as global variables, it says it can't find the module `foo` and I believe its running the function inside `foo.py` not inside `project.py` like iI ant it to, how can I have it so the user imports the module and can run the function locally in `project.py`?

Comment: are `foo.py` and `project.py` in the same directory

Comment: Use `from foo import a, b, c` in `project.py`

Comment: It sounds like you want what's known as dynamic scoping, where variable resolution is relative to the site of a function call instead of the function definition. Experience has taught the world that this is a horrible, horrible idea. Use J.F. Sebastian's suggestion, and if you think you still want to do what you're asking for later, stop and look for a better way.

Comment: The way you write it it seems like `setup` should be in `project.py`. `foo.a` in module `foo` makes little sense.